DNS not working when transparent proxy is active
I started a ShadowSocks(Socks5) tproxy and configured iptable to route all the traffic towards it. It is working and listenning to traffic, I can access webpages by directly typing in the ip address; However it's not resolving any domain/dns requests.
I tested the network by the following commands, which supposably means that the network is working and it's just the dns not working. Note that everything is perfectly fine if I just use the normal proxy of ShadowSocks. I started the tproxy with this command model ss-redir -s ServerIP -p ServerPort -m EncryptionMethod -k MyPasswd -b 127.0.0.1 -l 60080 --no-delay -u -T -v, and I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 Noble on gen 6+ kernel
$ nc -vz 172.217.163.46 80
Connection to 172.217.163.46 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!

$ nc -vz 172.217.163.46 443
Connection to 172.217.163.46 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!

$ nc -v -u 127.0.0.1 60080
Connection to 127.0.0.1 60080 port [udp/*] succeeded!

$ nc -zvu 8.8.8.8 53
Connection to 8.8.8.8 53 port [udp/domain] succeeded!

$ wget 172.217.163.46
--2024-11-06 18:05:45--  http://172.217.163.46/
Connecting to 172.217.163.46:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2024-11-06 18:05:45--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.google.com’

$ dig google.com @1.1.1.1
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: timed out


Here is the ip tables config
    ##################### SSREDIR #####################
    iptables -t mangle -N SSREDIR

    # connection-mark -> packet-mark
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -m mark --mark 0x2333 -j RETURN

    # ignore traffic sent to ss-server
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -p tcp -d ServerIP --dport ServerPort -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -p udp -d ServerIP --dport ServerPort -j RETURN

    # ignore traffic sent to reserved addresses
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 0.0.0.0/8          -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 10.0.0.0/8         -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 100.64.0.0/10      -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 127.0.0.0/8        -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 169.254.0.0/16     -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 172.16.0.0/12      -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 192.0.0.0/24       -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 192.0.2.0/24       -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 192.88.99.0/24     -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 192.168.0.0/16     -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 198.18.0.0/15      -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 198.51.100.0/24    -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 203.0.113.0/24     -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 224.0.0.0/4        -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 240.0.0.0/4        -j RETURN
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN

    # mark the first packet of the connection
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -p tcp --syn                      -j MARK --set-mark 0x2333
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j MARK --set-mark 0x2333

    # packet-mark -> connection-mark
    iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -j CONNMARK --save-mark

    ##################### OUTPUT #####################
    # proxy the outgoing traffic from this machine
    iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL ! --dst-type LOCAL -j SSREDIR
    iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL ! --dst-type LOCAL -j SSREDIR

    ##################### PREROUTING #####################
    # proxy traffic passing through this machine (other->other)
    iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m addrtype ! --src-type LOCAL ! --dst-type LOCAL -j SSREDIR
    iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -m addrtype ! --src-type LOCAL ! --dst-type LOCAL -j SSREDIR

    # hand over the marked package to TPROXY for processing
    iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x2333 -j TPROXY --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --on-port 60080
    iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -m mark --mark 0x2333 -j TPROXY --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --on-port 60080

    ip route add local default dev lo table 100
    ip rule  add fwmark 0x2333        table 100
    ip rule  del   table 100 &>/dev/null
    ip route flush table 100 &>/dev/null



Is shadowsocks supposed to include a built-in DNS server? And if not, then is your server running any other DNS resolver service?

I don't think shadowsocks has a build-in DNS server nor does the server. I've been using client side DNS like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8

You’ll have to configure a local DNS forwarder to handle DNS requests and route them through ShadowSocks. As I’ve said before, something free and simple like dnsmasq would work well.

Because neither ShadowSocks nor the server provides a DNS service, as I said, you’ll probably have to configure a local DNS forwarder to handle DNS requests and route them through ShadowSocks.
I would probably use dnsmasq, because it's simple and lightweight, and does the job.


First, install it with apt or whatever packet manager you use.
Configure dnsmasq:


Configuer dnsmasq to use your preferred DNS servers (e.g., 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8). Edit /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.8.8


Set dnsmasq to listen on a specific local IP and port, like 127.0.0.1:5353, by adding:

listen-address=127.0.0.1
port=5353


Redirect DNS Requests to ShadowSocks:


Update /etc/resolv.conf to point DNS queries to dnsmasq:

nameserver 127.0.0.1


Modify your iptables rules (something I only recently learnt how to do), to redirect DNS traffic (port 53) to 127.0.0.1:60080 (ShadowSocks’ TProxy):

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j TPROXY --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --on-port 60080


Restart dnsmasq and test it (might need sudo priviledges, mind you.):

systemctl restart dnsmasq



Why did you decide that a local dnsmasq would make it work? It is still sending dns requests to dns servers just like before. I followed your instruction and dns resolve would work when the tproxy is not on, will still fail after the iptables and tproxy is set up.  
$ dig @127.0.0.1 google.com
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: timed out

Why would my original systemd-resolvd be different to dnsmasq anyways?

Well if you’re using systemd-resolvd then obviously dnsmasq doesn’t make a difference- I didn’t know this, sorry. So then the problem must be with iptables- but I see you’ve asked another question. Cheers.

I'm kinda confused now, because from my point of view the iptables are perfectly fine, but how is it not working?

@james Look: if you are already using systemd-resolvd, then the dns server isn't the problem. If you think that iptables is working fine, then it must be a problem with the tproxy.

the thing is that I'm not even sure if this is the problem of iptables or the problem with the proxy. Any idea on how I can test it?

@james you could use Wireshark, it’s probably your best bet. But didn’t you literally just say that iptables seemed to be working fine?

I said I think it's fine, but who knows? There is always some thing wrong when using ubuntu, those hidden litle things that mess up the whole thing
